# Firebase Same User IDs Across Devices, but Inconsistent Data Retrieval

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm facing challenges while integrating Firebase authentication using the MakeItSo App project from the official Compose documentation. Unlike the original project, which allows anonymous authentication, my application only permits authenticated users to make and read changes.

Data Models:

```kotlin
data class User(
    val id: String = "",
)

data class Client(
    @DocumentId val id: String = "",
    val name: String = "",
    val phone: String = "",
    val city: String = "",
    val userId: String = ""

)
```

When saving data to Firestore, I noticed that the user ID appears to be the same for different devices. However, during data retrieval, the documents are not found.

Firestore Rules:

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2023, 12, 8);
    }
  }
}
```

Checking the database, I observed that the IDs assigned on two devices to users with the same account are the same, and upon saving, they are stored with the same IDs:

```
userId : xxx" // // Data saved on the emulator 1
userId : xxx" // // Data saved on the emulator 2
```

Regardless of the device, I want Firestore queries to return data for any user with the same ID. Below are relevant code snippets:

AccountServiceImpl

```kotlin
class AccountServiceImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val auth: FirebaseAuth
) : AccountService {
    override val currentUserId: String
        get() = auth.currentUser?.uid.orEmpty()

    override val hasUser: Boolean
        get() = auth.currentUser != null

    override val currentUser: Flow<User>
        get() = callbackFlow {
            val listener =
                FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener { auth ->
                    this.trySend(auth.currentUser?.let { User(it.uid) } ?: User())
                }
            auth.addAuthStateListener(listener)
            awaitClose { auth.removeAuthStateListener(listener) }
        }

    override suspend fun authenticate(email: String, password: String) {
        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).await()
    }

    override suspend fun signOut() {
        auth.signOut()
    }
}
```

StorageServiceImpl

```kotlin
class StorageServiceImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val firestore: FirebaseFirestore,
    private val auth: AccountService
) : StorageService {

    @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
    override val clients: Flow<List<Client>>
        get() = auth.currentUser.flatMapLatest { user ->
            firestore.collection(CLIENTS_COLLECTION)
                .whereEqualTo(USER_ID_FIELD, user.id)
                .orderBy(ORDER_CLIENTS_BY)
                .dataObjects()
        }


    override suspend fun getClient(clientId: String): Client? =
        firestore.collection(CLIENTS_COLLECTION).document(clientId).get().await().toObject()


    override suspend fun saveClient(client: Client): String {
        val clientWithUserId = client.copy(userId = auth.currentUserId)
        return firestore.collection(CLIENTS_COLLECTION).add(clientWithUserId).await().id
    }

    override suspend fun updateClient(client: Client) {
        firestore.collection(CLIENTS_COLLECTION).document(client.id).set(client).await()
    }

    override suspend fun deleteClient(clientId: String) {
        firestore.collection(CLIENTS_COLLECTION).document(clientId).delete().await()
    }

    companion object {
        const val CLIENTS_COLLECTION = "clients"
        const val ORDER_CLIENTS_BY = "name"
        const val USER_ID_FIELD = "userId"
    }
}
```

Even though the user IDs are the same (i.e., login is done with the same credentials), I can't access the data as expected.

Example of different devices with the same account, email, and password, same ID in the database, but different data:

[image] [image]

Any suggestions on how to ensure unique IDs for authenticated users and enable consistent data retrieval across devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `saveClient()` is using `collection().add()` to add a Document, which will give you an auto-generated ID.  To many, this value seems "random" (it isn't but it also isn't predictable).

Your `getClient()` is using `collection().doc(clientId).get()` which assumes that the ID of the document in the CLIENTS_COLLECTION is equal to the ID of the `clientId`...but I don't see that you have code which is explicitly setting the ID of a document to be the `clientId`.

If you need "predictable IDs", then use `collection().set()` and not `collection().add()` to create a document.

Comment: You can see the clientId in this line:
`val clientWithUserId = client.copy(userId = auth.currentUserId)
return firestore.collection(CLIENTS_COLLECTION).add(clientWithUserId).await().id`

Nevertheless, the error was in the "Index" section of Firebase, where I needed to add an index to the query. I still don't know exactly why, but that solved the problem.

Comment: You want to be watching your JS console for errors/warnings coming from Firestore.  The error message would have given you details as to what index was required and why.

If you find that you have too many errors in your console...well....fix all of them!  